# RavenDB.Client.Embedded disappears after I try to build it

Tags: c#, nuget, ravendb

I'm following tutorial, installed RanvenDB embeeded and write:

```
public static IDocumentStore archives =
    new EmbeddableDocumentStore { DataDirectory = "~/DataStore" };
```

then I let VS to find where is EmbeddableDocumentStore so and I add:

```
using Raven.Client.Embedded;
```

No errors yet and everything looks fine. Then I build:

> Archives.cs(10,20): error CS0234: The type or namespace name
>   'Embedded' does not exist in the namespace 'Raven.Client' (are you
>   missing an assembly reference?)
>
> Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings

And now it's error and there is no Embedded...

If I remove package.config and run install Ravendb Embedded again it will become green (with no errors) again but just after I run build...

How to repair it?

(tested different version : same result)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure that you are building for the FULL .NET framework, and not just the client profile.